# HttpGet object name prefix removal from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is an example model and function declaration from my project

```
public class ActionLogModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Log id
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Source of action
    /// </summary>
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLog([FromUri] ActionLogModel log)
```

It works fine but my URL requires each parameter to be prefixed with 'log' e.g. log.Id

Is there a global parameter I could use to flatten it so the prefix is not required in my URLs?

Comment: Try to change your attribute to `[FromUri(Name = "")]`

Comment: That works, however, I'm after more of a global setting so all functions behave the same way with their parameters.

Comment: But you have `FromUri` attribute in many actions, why don't simply add `Name = ""` (I am not sure that you can have it globally)?

Comment: I think you may be right, I'll have to go with that as my solution for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your attribute from:

```
[FromUri]
```

to:

```
[FromUri(Name = "")]
```

I'm not sure that you can set it globally. You should change this attribute in every action.